# Using Mono on Linux OWIN web api https exception when I use curl to connect

Tags: c#, linux, asp.net-web-api, https, mono

System:
Ubuntu v16.10 with the latest alpha 9 of mono v4.8.0.429 as of Jan 18, 2017.

I've been trying to implement a Web API (REST) using c# on a OWIN self host.

Here's a snipit of my `main program.cs` file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Owin.Hosting;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading;

namespace RestController_test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string baseUrl = "https://web.local:12357/";  
            using (WebApp.Start<Startup>(url: baseUrl))  
            {  
                Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);
            }
        )
    )
)
```

Super simple with a `startup.cs` file that looks like

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth;
using Owin;
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace RestController_test
{

  public class Startup  
  {  
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)  
    {  
      var config = new HttpConfiguration ();
      config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
      name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
    appBuilder.UseWebApi (config);
  }
```

All this is from sample code I've found around the net.
Then I've got a simple controller that passes back some simple info:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace RestController_test.Controller
{
    public class ProductsController : ApiController
    {
        Product[] products = new Product[]
        {
            new Product { Id = 1, Name = "Tomato Soup", Category = "Groceries", Price = 1 },
            new Product { Id = 2, Name = "Yo-yo", Category = "Toys", Price = 3.75M },
            new Product { Id = 3, Name = "Hammer", Category = "Hardware", Price = 16.99M }
        };
        public IEnumerable<Product> Get()
        {
            helper.write ("Controller Products", User); 
            return products;
        }
        public IHttpActionResult Get(int id)
        {
            var product = products.FirstOrDefault((p) => p.Id == id);
            if (product == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return Ok(product);
        }
        // POST /api/Products
        public void PostProduct([FromBody]string value)
        {
            // let's add a vlaue to products
            //new Product {  Id = 4, Name = vlaue, }
        }
    }
}
```

This all works great if my weburl is http://web.local:12347 (where 12347 is not on a port that has an ssl cert associated with it.

I've installed Xamian v4.8 alpha rc9 for Windows and it works fine, I get TLS v1.2 working when I do a curl on my web page. - edit, after looking closer, it looks like it was using the MS libraries, not the mono ones.

it had worked (not sure what changed when I updated) with curl and got a tls v1.0 response. but firefox and postman caused an exception. since it doesn't work now, I'll give the error message that I get now and the different message when I enable btls.

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
at Mono.Net.Security.MobileAuthenticatedStream.ProcessAuthentication (System.Net.LazyAsyncResult lazyResult) [0x0007e] in   <405ddf444dab4253998152605d2d9311>:0
at Mono.Net.Security.MobileAuthenticatedStream.AuthenticateAsServer (System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate serverCertificate, System.Boolean clientCertificateRequired, System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols enabledSslProtocols, System.Boolean checkCertificateRevocation) [0x00010] in <405ddf444dab4253998152605d2d9311>:0
at Mono.Net.Security.Private.MonoSslStreamWrapper.AuthenticateAsServer (System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate serverCertificate, System.Boolean clientCertificateRequired, System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols enabledSslProtocols, System.Boolean checkCertificateRevocation) [0x00006] in <405ddf444dab4253998152605d2d9311>:0
at System.Net.HttpConnection.Init () [0x0001d] in <405ddf444dab4253998152605d2d9311>:0
at System.Net.HttpConnection..ctor (System.Net.Sockets.Socket sock, System.Net.EndPointListener epl, System.Boolean secure, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate cert) [0x00096] in <405ddf444dab4253998152605d2d9311>:0
at System.Net.EndPointListener.ProcessAccept (System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs args) [0x00052] in <405ddf444dab4253998152605d2d9311>:0
at System.Net.EndPointListener.OnAccept (System.Object sender, System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs e) [0x00000] in <405ddf444dab4253998152605d2d9311>:0
at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.OnCompleted (System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs e) [0x00014] in <405ddf444dab4253998152605d2d9311>:0
at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.Complete () [0x00000] in <405ddf444dab4253998152605d2d9311>:0
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.<AcceptAsyncCallback>m__0 (System.IAsyncResult ares) [0x000a0] in <405ddf444dab4253998152605d2d9311>:0
at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncResult+<Complete>c__AnonStorey0.<>m__0 (System.Object _) [0x00000] in <405ddf444dab4253998152605d2d9311>:0
at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem () [0x00019] in <111faffb08a0411a893ed183e82e8c28>:0
at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch () [0x00096] in <111faffb08a0411a893ed183e82e8c28>:0
at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback () [0x00000] in <111faffb08a0411a893ed183e82e8c28>:0
```

What I understand to get ssl 1.2 working with mono 4.8 is you need to add a mono variable `MONO_TLS_PROVIDER = btls`. I did this in my project options under
RUN -> General (Variable and value).

I've added the various certificates to the machine store with
`sudo certmgr -add -c -m Trust DevRoot.cer` (Root certificate that I've created)
`sudo certmgr -add -c -m My web.local.cer`
and added it to the port 12357 with
`httpcfg -add -port 12357 -cert web.local.cer -pvk web.local.pvk`

I've also removed all of these from machine store, and added them locally with the same exception. (no `sudo` and removed the `-m`)

Something I did read was to use `btls-cert-sync`, but within Linux I can't find it anywhere on my system. is this a package I should be installing?

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Mono is open source, so you might check the related code to see what might be the cause. It should give you some hints.

Comment: this is a mono bug, please report it here: http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/

Comment: I updated the issue above with other tests I've done: Updated to RC9 v4.8.0.429, and installed Xamarin on Windows and tested the code. (It works under windows). I've posted the bug onto Bugzilla, https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=51617

Comment: Looks like Xamarin on windows is using the MS libraries, so it's not working under windows.